# Problem clipping background to coreimage aztec generation with CIBlendWithMask

Tags: ios, objective-c, filter, mask, core-image

I am trying to add an image background to a generated atec code so far I can get the aztec code to generate but am having trouble with the CIBlendWithMask filter, i'm not sure exactly what i'm doing wrong I believe the user selected background as kCIInputBackgroundImageKey is correct and the aztec output image as the kCIInputImageKey is correct, I think where i'm going wrong is the kCIInputMaskImageKey but not exactly sure why I need to do I thought the aztec output would be a sufficient mask image - do I need to select the color or something to get the background clipping to the aztec image?

```
        CIFilter *aztecFilter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIAztecCodeGenerator"];
        CIFilter *colorFilter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIFalseColor"];
        [aztecFilter setValue:stringData forKey:@"inputMessage"];
        
        [colorFilter setValue:aztecFilter.outputImage forKey:@"background"];
        
        NSData* imageData = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"usertheme"];
        
        CIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData].CIImage;


        
        [colorFilter setValue:[CIColor colorWithCGColor:[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]] forKey:@"inputColor0"];
        [colorFilter setValue:[CIColor colorWithRed:1 green:1 blue:1 alpha:0] forKey:@"inputColor1"];
        
    
        
        
         CIFilter *blendFilter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIBlendWithMask"];
         [blendFilter setValue:colorFilter.outputImage forKey:kCIInputImageKey];
         [blendFilter setValue:image forKey:kCIInputBackgroundImageKey];
         [blendFilter setValue:colorFilter.outputImage forKey:kCIInputMaskImageKey];
```

Trying to create something like this but for aztec codes instead of QR

[image: see picture here]

Comment: *"add an image background to a generated aztec code"* ... it would help if you show an example of your "goal" image.

Comment: Added to the post now :)

Answer (score 0):

You may be over-thinking this a bit...

You can use the `CIBlendWithMask` filter with only a background image and a mask image.

So, if we start with a gradient image (you may be generating it on-the-fly):

[image]

Then generate the Aztec Code image (yellow outline is just to show the frame):

[image]

We can use that code image as the mask.

Here is sample code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor systemYellowColor];
    
    // create a vertical stack view
    UIStackView *sv = [UIStackView new];
    sv.axis = UILayoutConstraintAxisVertical;
    sv.spacing = 8;
    sv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    
    [self.view addSubview:sv];
    
    // add 3 image views to the stack view
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        UIImageView *imgView = [UIImageView new];
        [sv addArrangedSubview:imgView];
        [imgView.widthAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:240].active = YES;
        [imgView.heightAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:imgView.widthAnchor].active = YES;
    }

    [self.view addSubview:sv];
    [sv.centerXAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.centerXAnchor].active = YES;
    [sv.centerYAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.centerYAnchor].active = YES;

    // load a gradient image for the background
    UIImage *gradientImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bkgGradient"];
    
    // put it in the first image view
    ((UIImageView *)sv.arrangedSubviews[0]).image = gradientImage;
    
    // create aztec filter
    CIFilter *aztecFilter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIAztecCodeGenerator"];
    
    // give it some string data
    NSString *qrString = @"My string to encode";
    NSData *stringData = [qrString dataUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [aztecFilter setValue:stringData forKey:@"inputMessage"];

    // get the generated aztec image
    CIImage *aztecCodeImage = aztecFilter.outputImage;

    // scale it to match the background gradient image
    float scaleX = gradientImage.size.width / aztecCodeImage.extent.size.width;
    float scaleY = gradientImage.size.height / aztecCodeImage.extent.size.height;
    
    aztecCodeImage = [[aztecCodeImage imageBySamplingNearest] imageByApplyingTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(scaleX, scaleY)];

    // convert to UIImage and set the middle image view
    UIImage *scaledCodeImage = [UIImage imageWithCIImage:aztecCodeImage scale:[UIScreen mainScreen].scale orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];
    ((UIImageView *)sv.arrangedSubviews[1]).image = scaledCodeImage;

    // create a blend with mask filter
    CIFilter *blendFilter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIBlendWithMask"];

    // set the background image
    CIImage *bkgInput = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:[gradientImage CGImage]];
    [blendFilter setValue:bkgInput forKey:kCIInputBackgroundImageKey];
    
    // set the mask image
    [blendFilter setValue:aztecCodeImage forKey:kCIInputMaskImageKey];
    
    // get the blended CIImage
    CIImage *output = [blendFilter outputImage];
    
    // convert to UIImage
    UIImage *blendedImage = [UIImage imageWithCIImage:output scale:[UIScreen mainScreen].scale orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];
    
    // set the bottom image view to the result
    ((UIImageView *)sv.arrangedSubviews[2]).image = blendedImage;

}
```

which produces:

[image]